# caprover Database initi One Click App failed

Tags: mysql, caprover, postgresql-initdb

023-11-17T04:33:18.129340584Z 2023-11-17T04:33:18.129241Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-11-17T04:33:18.129343109Z 2023-11-17T04:33:18.129288Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-17T04:33:18.129430258Z 2023-11-17T04:33:18.129360Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29) MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Tried reinstalling Caprover on sercer but after few deployments it came

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.